# Autohotkey - Pressing 3 keys at once

Tags: autohotkey

I tried the following AutoHotkey macro to press the c, f and k keys all at once:

```
1::
SendInput cfk {enter}
Return
```

This code is just giving cfk, but doesnt press this keys at once.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8):

In the way that you've done things at the moment the first key is released before the second is pressed. You need to tell AutoHotkey to hold the key down. Try this:

```
1::
SendInput {c down}{f down}{k down}{c up}{f up}{k up} {enter}
Return
```

This tells AutoHotkey to press the key, but don't forget to tell it to lift the key up again afterwards ;).

Comment: it's strange that I write key up but some key is stuck not up